# need to have collapsible element in php using js and html

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I need to make one section in a table collapsible for making it look prettier.  I have the following code snippets in editor_transdata.php

```
<script language="javascript">
function toggle_messege(type) {
    document.getElementById("div_messege").style.display = type;
    document.getElementById("hreh_close").style.display = type;
    }
</script>

<link type="text/css" href="../style/collapse.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
```

and to display what I want to be collapsible I have this

```
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<a class="right" ';
            echo 'href=\"javascript:toggle_messege(\'inline\')\" ';
            echo 'id=\'href_about\'>';              
            echo 'Summary </a> <br />';
            echo '<a class="hide" ';
            echo 'href=\"javascript:toggle_messege(\'none\')\" ';
            echo 'id=\'hreh_close\'> (Close)</a>';

            echo '<div id=\'div_messege\' class=\'hide\'>' . $row['datasummary'];
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</td>';
```

my css page is as follows

```
.hide {
display:none;
}
.right {
float:right;
}
```

however, when displayed I get something that looks like this and is not collapsible it looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vCTJ.jpg
the paragraph should not be displayed until summary is clicked, nor should close.
and clicking on summary or close gives the following error:

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

Any information as to what I can do to fix this problem would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Make your CSS have a .show{} class, and hide the element by default:

```
#element{display:none}
.show{display:block}
```

Then make your js toggle the class instead of toggling style type. You can use either jQuery or VanillaJS for this - whatever is your style.

In jquery it would look like this:

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $("#element").toggleClass("show");
});
```

Finally, your html elements that you want to show and hide would look like this:

```
echo '<a href="#" class="toggle">Click this to toggle</a>\n
    <div id="element">\n'
        . $row['datasummary'] .
    '</div>';
```

### EDIT

Edited to show phping the html, like you want. And to add this thought:

Or you could just use jQuery's `.toggle()` function:

```
$(".toggle").click(function(){
    $("#element").toggle();
});
```

Comment: So I implemented what you have here, but I still get the element div displaying when it should be initially hidden.  This leads me to believe it has something to do with how I am implementing the css in the php file.  I use this line:

`<link type="text/css" href="../style/collapse.css"` `rel="stylesheet" media="all" />`

Comment: Where is your css located? STart with your root directory and give me the tree

Comment: editor_transdata.php is in ../sop/

I have jquery.js and json2.js in /sop/js/

I have collapse.css in sop/style/

**sorry for my terrible formating**

Comment: try putting in the whole url to the css file in the href.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new js function:

```
    function showDiv(divName){
    //alert(divName);
    div = document.getElementById(divName);
    div.style.display="block";
    }
```

and used the following for my php implementation:

```
 echo '<a href="#collapse" name=' . $i . ' onclick="showDiv(this.name)">Summary</a>
<div id=' . $i . ' style="display:none">'
. $row['datasummary'] . 
'</div>';
```

and my css file:

```
#collapse{
display:none;
}

#collapse:target{
display:block;
}
```

The issue with declaring the location of the collapse.css file was incorrect. I changed the directory to "/sop/style/collapse.css"

Thank you for your help.